# ByteArrayOutputStream vs FileOutputStream from memory usage and performance point of view

Tags: java, file-io, arrays

What I want to do is to download a file from the web server. When I traced the code, two programmers uses ByteArrayOutputStream  and  FileOutputStream differently to download file in the same scenario. These are

- **Case 1**: use `ByteArrayOutputStream` to create a file and download it.
- **Case 2**: use `FileOutputStream` to temporarily create a file under web  server and download it and then delete this file.

PS: Case 2 file is larger than case 1 file.

Can I use `ByteArrayOutputStream` to both cases? Is there any intention to use `FileOutputStream` in second case? What I want to know is from performance and memory point of view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream` is in memory and `FileOutputStream` is a file. The implications are obvious. `ByteArrayOutputStream` is faster but consider downloading a 10Gb file... This would seem to open a nice security hole in the program - just feed it a large file.

Comment: It all depends on the size the file you are downloading. `ByteArrayOutputStream` is good for smaller size file.

Comment: It's ridiculous to compare them at all. One uses nothing but memory, at bus speeds, and no disk, the other uses little memory and as much disk as necessary, at disk I/O speeds.

Comment: @BoristheSpider ByteArrayOutputStream is limited to just under 2GB as it uses a byte[] ;)

Answer (score 3):

Combining Boris The Spider's and Peter Lawrey's to an answer:
`ByteArrayOutputStream` is in memory and `FileOutputStream` is a file. The implications are obvious. `ByteArrayOutputStream` is faster but consider downloading a 10Gb file... This would seem to open a nice security hole in the program - just feed it a large file.
Also `ByteArrayOutputStream` is limited to just under 2GB as it uses a byte[]